# created Pdf by using pdf print through webview. it creates large size pdf around 19 mb.but images are around 500, 600 kb already compressed

Tags: java, android, pdf

I am creating  a PDF in my android app by using pdf print through `WebvView`. It creates large size PDF around 19 MB.but there are 4,5 images which  around 500, 600 KB max.i am unable to reduce the PDF file size.

```
public static void createWebPrintJob(Activity activity, WebView webView, File directory, String fileName, final Callback callback) {

    //check the marshmallow permission
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (activity.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            activity.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            callback.failure();
           return;
        }
    }

    String jobName = activity.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Document";
    PrintAttributes attributes = null;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        attributes = new PrintAttributes.Builder()
                .setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.ISO_A4)
                .setResolution(new PrintAttributes.Resolution("pdf", "pdf", 100, 100))
                .setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are the resolutions of images?

Comment: Among all 4,5  images maximum resolution is width = 3264 pixels
Height= 2448 pixels & image size is 528.9 kb

Comment: I think images in PDFs are stored as raw image data, not necessarily compressed in any way, with 4 or 5 images of that size that is an awful lot of data, can you make them smaller?

Comment: Images _can_ be stored with compression in PDF.